# How can I fix this: (Non-canonical signature: S value is unnecessarily high)

Tags: signature, ecdsa

I've written a small script that will create a bitcoin transaction from scratch, using an [ECDSA library](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/ruby_ecdsa). It works, but sometimes I get this error:

**64: non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Non-canonical signature: S value is unnecessarily high)**

I found this reply answer on [bitcoin talk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1356430.msg13810572#msg13810572):

> The signature is composed of two values, the r value and the s value. 
>   In your third input, the s value is greater than N/2, which is not
>   allowed.  Just add in some code that if s is greater than N/2, then s
>   = N - s.

But what exactly is `N`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though N is the **order** of the elliptic curve.

Or in other words, the *number of possible points* on the secp256k1 curve.

```
N = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the parameters of elliptic curve. The [secp256k1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1) curve used in bitcoin have parameter N set to:

N = FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE BAAEDCE6 AF48A03B BFD25E8C D0364141