# Cannot broadcast bitcoin testnet transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, blockchain, testnet, blockcypher

Error validating transaction: Error running script for input 0 referencing 9a2cd138476c598cced94a6c8bd6c8b2c6a268a763700d654324614aff799ceb at 0: Script was NOT verified successfully..

My transaction - 0100000001eb9c79ff4a612443650d7063a768a2c6b2c8d68b6c4ad9ce8c596c4738d12c9a000000006a473044022076731c7063163d36d0650b7573ec46af795c46f7860940d4ee8a48f7b1c66c0d0220ca417e99b3549ce80ed1db7964db3597cabf709cc614a22f1fe7b81769775d360121028144f0617ca9f46faf22c3a2aabe2b5a70b41b33d943eedeab45fb0ea39db03bffffffff02409c0000000000001976a9146bcf529af56090cc7cc1aa846286eec1651991d888acf00edf03000000001976a91481d52f0d91561dde46689640dd79d80a32fdadae88ac00000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you let us know, which tool or software you used to generate this output? I have one observation:

```
    47: OP_DATA_0x47:        push hex 47 (decimal 71) bytes on stack
    30: OP_SEQUENCE_0x30:    type tag indicating SEQUENCE, begin sigscript
    44: OP_LENGTH_0x44:      length of R + S
    02: OP_INT_0x02:         type tag INTEGER indicating length
    20: OP_LENGTH_0x20:      this is SIG R (32 Bytes)
        76731C7063163D36:D0650B7573EC46AF
        795C46F7860940D4:EE8A48F7B1C66C0D
    02: OP_INT_0x02:         type tag INTEGER indicating length
    20: OP_LENGTH_0x20:      this is SIG S (32 Bytes)
        CA417E99B3549CE8:0ED1DB7964DB3597
        CABF709CC614A22F:1FE7B81769775D36
    01: OP_SIGHASHALL:       this terminates the ECDSA signature (ASN1-DER structure)
```

The S-Value starts with CA417E99... this value in a signed int is above the allowed value. See Pieter's post at the bottom [of this link](http://bitcoin-development.narkive.com/OOU2XVSG/bitcoin-development-who-is-creating-non-der-signatures). 
Values higher than one should be preceeded by "00". But before doing so, it should be checked wether it is larger than N/2. [Further explanation here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/68254/how-can-i-fix-this-non-canonical-signature-s-value-is-unnecessarily-high).